# unable to display turboVNC

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

I'm trying to use [turboVNC](https://www.turbovnc.org/) for remote application. I have installed virtualGL package (`virtualgl32_2.6_amd64.deb`) and then turboVNC (`turbovnc_2.1.90_amd64.deb`).

I'm using

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Processor : Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E7300 @ 2.66GHz × 2 
Graphic : AMD RV610 (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.15.0-33-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
OS Type : 64-bit
```

I do not receive any error when installing, but afterwards, I'm unable to launch turboVNC.

It appears in `Application`; when I click on it, something appears briefly in the launcher side bar menu and then nothing.

I tried to remove and re-install, I still have the same problem.

Running:

```
~$ vncserver
```

returns:

```
New 'user1-OptiPlex-760:8 (user)' desktop is user-OptiPlex-760:8

Starting applications specified in /home/User/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/User/.vnc/user-OptiPlex-760:8.log
```

I'm able to run vncserver from TurboVNC but not open the graphical window. I get a new error message:

> Could not find libjawt.so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install java in your system, do it with:

`sudo apt install default-jre`